# Multilevel cache and maximum miss rate

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, multi-level

the first level(L1) has hit rate 600 psec, miss rate 10% and miss penalnty 80 nsec. I add a second level cache(L2) with hit rate 5 nsec. I am trying to find th e maximum miss rate for the second level,considering that the combination of the caches (L1 + L2) has double efficiency than the one-level cache L1.

I am using these forms
Average memory access time = Hit time (L1) + Miss rate (L1) x Miss penalty (L1)
Miss penalty (L1) = Hit time (L2) + Miss rate (L2) x Miss penalty (L2)

the solution i get is 40 %,but the correct answer is 9,25 %.
can anyone help?

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

```
avg     = 8.6 = 0.6 + 0.1*80  
1/2*avg = 4.3 = 0.6 + 0.1*(5 + x*80)  
=>        3.2 = x*8  
=>        x = 0.4
```

So, it seems that you answer is correct under assumptions that
 - "Average memory access time" does not include any other time value for various secondary effects;
 - Double efficiency means that it takes a half time in average.

Comment: but still the correct answer is 9,25% and i am not finding something wrong with my calcutations. i am concerned about the word "maximum". Our calculations seem to answer the question "what is the miss rate of L2",not the "maximum miss rate of L2". I assume that there is a slight detail between these questions,but its too difficult to find it

Comment: obviously. if miss rate of L2 is 0.4 , then max miss rate of L2 can not be 0.0925.  
so our brain caches are missing something.